# Prove that $ f\left(\bigcup _{i\in I}A_i\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}f(A_i)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f \colon A\rightarrow B$ be a function. Furthermore let $I$ be a set and $\forall i\in I,A_i\subseteq A$

**(1)** $\displaystyle f\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}f(A_i)$

**(2)** $\displaystyle f\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\right)\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in I}f(A_i)$

---

I just can't get my head around this question, it's been driving me crazy

Comment: Do you know what the question is asking, in words?

Comment: There are three inclusions to be proven. Can you start any of them?

Comment: Ive basically proven to myself by slotting in values but I've considered a few methods of proving which led me down the wrong route.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Suppose $y\in \displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}f(A_i)$. Then there is some $i\in I$ and $x\in A_i$ such that $y=f(x)$. We thus have… [what?].